# Cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays [SystemC]

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2013, systemc

Im using VS2013 along with the SystemC library from Allegro. I was trying to initialize two arrays as follows:

```
int pathObs1[19] = {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int Map[10][4] = {
    { 0, 3, 1, 4 }, //Grid 1
    { 1, 3, 2, 4 }, //Grid 2
    { 2, 3, 3, 4 }, //Grid 3
    { 3, 3, 4, 4 }, //Grid 4
    { 4, 3, 5, 4 }, //Grid 5
    { 5, 3, 6, 4 }, //Grid 6
    { 6, 3, 7, 4 }, //Grid 7
    { 6, 2, 7, 3 }, //Grid 8
    { 6, 1, 7, 2 }, //Grid 9
    { 6, 0, 7, 1 }  //Grid 10
    };
```

However i received the error the above error. I saw some questions on SO which had the same issue, however I dont think they were dealing with SystemC. Any easy workaround for this in SystemC since im trying to initialize inside my SC_MODULE header/constructor?

Edit: I had a typo in my array initialization. Still get the same error.

Comment: You are assigning 4 values to an array that has only 3 elements.

Comment: The error with this might be clear enough I guess.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Yes, it was a typo on my part when i wrote the question. I still get the error in the title. Even if i initialize an array size 2 in my header, i get that error. It only lets me initialize the array values in the cpp/main which i'd rather avoid.

Comment: Ah! You are in C++! In C this would not be a problem (as long as there are 3 values).

Answer (score 1):

2dArray[m][n] means m rows n columns so you can keep n values in each row but in your code you defined matrix which had 3 columns but still you are assigning 4 values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop for filling the array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib>

int main()
{
srand(time(null));
int map[10][4];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
  {
     map[i][j] = rand(); // you can write smth like rand() % 5 to make a limit of the values
  }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int[m][n]` and `int **arr` are not interchangeable.

Comment: I have preset values I want to use and they need to be at the specific indexes. So even for a 1d array, a loop would be meaningless because depending on the value of the index, the array value might be really different. I.e., it may go 1,2,3,4,5,3,7,9,10,4,2,1. I.e., to the program, the values seem random. But they actually have a meaning in the larger scope of it which i need to maintain.